# E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

I am trying to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

but I keep getting these errors

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I read in another answer that by using `sudo` these errors will be solved. But in my case I'm already using sudo. How to solve these errors?

Comment: You need to use `sudo` on the `apt-get upgrade` as well; the command after the '&&' is a separate command so isn't covered by the `sudo` on your first command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

the commands before and after && are separate commands, so `sudo` must be used by both commands.