# sudo apt-get update && apt upgrade tried to run this command and got a error

Tags: command-line, dpkg, root, npm, konqueror

I run the command  apt update and upgade but it gave this error .I tried the other methods like dpkg other fixes, but it did not get fixed. Also used grep command also

[the error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lDgP.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208449/e-could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-13-permission-d)

Comment: You're attempting to run `apt upgrade` without `sudo`....  You first command included the `sudo`, but the second command you provided did not.

Comment: ^^^ guiverc is correct here..

Answer (score 4):

Your command

```
sudo apt-get update && apt upgrade
```

contained two commands

1. `sudo apt-get update`

ie. here you elevated the privileges for your first `apt-get update` command.

If the first commands was successful (`&&` operand) you told the machine to run a second command

2. `apt upgrade`

this command you told the system to run with normal permissions; thus the *permission denied* error you received.  The `sudo` for the first command you gave was only for that first command, not both commands you entered due to the manner in which you wrote it.